# Sharing folder via batch script on french windows

Tags: batch-file

This is my batch script which I use to automatically share specific folder with "Everyone". As You might have noticed I have to first extract name in current installed language. For french version correct string is "Tout le monde" (Everyone). Problem is that I get only word "Tout" and everything after space is ignored.

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>net share SharedFolder="C:\Temp\SharedFolder" /GRANT:Tout,FULL
```

Result folder is not shared. Does anybody know how to improve this script in order to get full name with all spaces?

```
set MySid=S-1-1-0
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_account where SID='%MySid%' get name"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="Name" (
      set myvar=%%a
      goto :loop_end
   )
)
:loop_end

net share SharedFolder /DELETE /Y
net share SharedFolder="C:\Temp\SharedFolder" /GRANT:%myvar%,FULL
icacls "C:\Temp\SharedFolder" /T /C /Q /Grant:R *%MySid%:(OI)(CI)F
icacls "C:\Temp\SharedFolder" /T /C /Q /inheritance:e
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you'd shown the actual `wmic` output you are receiving. Based on my English-language version, I'd suggest

> Remove the space between the `=` and `"` in the `delims` clause.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set MySid=S-1-1-0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"wmic path win32_account where SID='%MySid%' get name"') do (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :striptrailing
 if not "!line!"=="Name" (
  set "myvar=!line!"
  goto :loop_end
 )
)
:loop_end

SET my
ECHO ==="%myvar%"---

GOTO :EOF

:striptrailing
IF NOT DEFINED line GOTO :EOF 
SET "line=%line:~0,-1%"
IF NOT DEFINED line GOTO :EOF 
if "%line:~-1%"==" " GOTO striptrailing
GOTO :eof
```

The `wmic` output lines are terminated by CRCRLF, not CRLF as is convention. Consequently, the last character of `%%a` when `delims` is empty is CR - and this confuses conventional processing.

With Space as a delimiter, `%%a` will acquire `Name` on the first line - but that is deceptive as the actual output is `Name [CR]` hence `delims` correctly selects `Name`.

On the next output line, in English you get `Everyone [CR]` which again "correctly" selects `Everyone`. This would fail if the user was `Atak Snajpera` as it would select just `Atak`.

So - we need to turn `delims` off to get the entire line, then manipulate `line` by removing the last character (which will be CR) **and** any trailing spaces. This must be done via a user-variable (I chose `line`) since substringing isn't allowed on metavariables.

In order to access the run-time value of the uservariable within the code-block, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion`.

The `:striptrailing` routine removes the last character unconditionally (we know it is a CR) and then continues while ever the last character of `line` is a space.

On reviewing the code, I believe it would be possible to make a couple of alterations.

First, since we know the first line will be `Name`, we can access the second line directly using `skip=1` in the `for`, which removes the requirement for the `if` and also for the `delayedexpansion` - all we need to do is move the routine to after `loop_end` to dispose of the terminal CR and spaces. And then there's no need to have `line` - `myvar` can be used instead.

Which I'll leave as an exercise for those interested...

Comment: if I remove space between the = and " I get this
http://i.cubeupload.com/dczqib.png