# Get output from command line and save into variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run the following command and get only the 2nd line and put it into a variable in a batch file for a string comparison

```
wmic baseboard get product
```

This outputs the following

```
Product
20BUS0YN00
```

I just want the 2nd line

This is what I am trying, but it gets the first line and the blank line afterwards

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic baseboard get Product') do set VAR=%%i
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140215/sharing-folder-via-batch-script-on-french-windows/46141020#46141020 and adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic baseboard get Product /value') do set VAR=%%i
```

Answer (score 0):

**sed** is one way to go for selecting the line:

```
VAR="$( wmic baseboard get Product | sed -n '2p' )"
```

You could also use perl, tail or other text processing utilities.

Comment: since when you can set a variable directly and do substitutions with `$` in windows batch?

Comment: I didn't see that this is in Windows, but I imagine you can pipe in the same way, no?

Comment: If you have sed installed on the machine, sure you can pipe wmic to sed. Unfortunately, you still can't do variable substitution like that. It would be great if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Because the output of WMIC has a 'problematic' ending `<CR><CR><LF>` sequence and the value of `Product` will usually have unwanted trailing spaces, *(you can check that with `Echo [%VAR%]`)*, I'd suggest something more like this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC BaseBoard Get Product'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Echo [%VAR%]
Timeout -1
Exit/B
    :Sub
    Set "VAR=%*"
```

Comment: @user1984300, please consider revising your acceptance of the currently chosen answer in favour of my answer which should more accurately output the string you required; Thank you.