# find wmic logicaldisk where DriveType

Tags: batch-file, cmd

how can set the DeviceID in a variable? output here is empty :(

```
in cmd working :
D:\>wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=5 get deviceid, volumename | find "bunny"
F:        bd50-bunny-comple
```

here is my bat:

```
@echo off
d:\bunny.iso


set isoname=bunny

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where DriveType^="5" Get DeviceID^,volumename ^|find "%isoname%"') do (
set %%a
)

echo %DeviceID%
echo %volumename%
```

Regards

Comment: I'd suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140215/… and adapt it.

Comment: So, your DeviceID given by your example above should be `F:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC LogicalDisk Where (DriveType='5') Get DeviceID, VolumeName"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "DID=%%B" & Set "VOL=%%C"
Echo Volume %VOL% is assigned to %DID%
Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Magoo's comment :

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
For /F "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where DriveType^="5" Get DeviceID^,volumename') DO (
    SET "line=%%a"
    CALL :striptrailing
    if not "!line!"=="" (
        set "myvar=!line!"
        goto :loop_end
    )
)
::****************************************
:loop_end
ECHO %myvar%
pause & GOTO :EOF
::****************************************
:striptrailing
IF NOT DEFINED line GOTO :EOF 
if "%line:~-1%"==" " GOTO striptrailing
GOTO :eof
::****************************************
```